# Object is never deleted by garbage collector

Tags: java, garbage-collection

The issue in this code is that the object referenced by *product* is never removed by the Garbage Collector (GC). I could verify this by watching the object as alive instance in the debugger of Eclipse.

```
public static List<ConditionalProbabilityTable> sumOut(List<ConditionalProbabilityTable> factorization, List<Variable> varsToSumOut) {

    List<ConditionalProbabilityTable> newFactorization = new ArrayList<>(factorization);

    for (Variable varToSumOut : varsToSumOut) {
        List<ConditionalProbabilityTable> relevantCpts = Inference.getAllCptsContaining(newFactorization, varToSumOut);
        ConditionalProbabilityTable product = Inference.multiplyAll(relevantCpts);

        ConditionalProbabilityTable marginal = ConditionalProbabilityTableOperation.marginalize(product, varToSumOut);
        newFactorization.removeAll(relevantCpts);
        newFactorization.add(marginal);
    }

    return newFactorization;
}
```

If I am not wrong, the object pointed by *product* is being kept alive because some reference to it (or maybe a reference for a member of product) is also alive. But I could not find such reference (I can add more code if necessary).

My goal is to get rid of the object pointed by *product*.

**EDIT**

Follows the code for `ConditionalProbabilityTableOperation.marginalize`:

```
public static ConditionalProbabilityTable marginalize(ConditionalProbabilityTable cpt, Variable variable) {
    ConditionalProbabilityTable marginalCpt = new ConditionalProbabilityTable();

    // Determine the scope of the new CPT.
    List<Variable> marginalCptLeftVariables = new ArrayList<>();
    marginalCptLeftVariables.addAll( cpt.getLeft());
    marginalCptLeftVariables.remove(variable);
    marginalCpt.addAllToLeft(marginalCptLeftVariables);

    List<Variable> marginalCptRightVariables = new ArrayList<>();
    marginalCptRightVariables.addAll(cpt.getRight());
    marginalCptRightVariables.remove(variable);
    marginalCpt.addAllToRight(marginalCptRightVariables);

    // Summation loop
    int j = 0;
    int[] assignments = new int[cpt.getNumberOfVariables()];
    int numberOfRowsInMarginal = marginalCpt.getNumberOfRows();
    List<Double> marginalValues = new ArrayList<>(Collections.nCopies(numberOfRowsInMarginal, 0.0));

    for (int i = 0; i < cpt.getNumberOfRows(); i++) {
        marginalValues.set(j, marginalValues.get(j) + cpt.getValue(i));

        for (int l = 0; l < cpt.getNumberOfVariables(); l++) {
            assignments[l] = assignments[l] + 1;
            int lVarCard = cpt.getVariable(l).getCardinality();
            if (assignments[l] == lVarCard) {
                assignments[l] = 0;
                j = j - (lVarCard - 1) * marginalCpt.getStride(cpt.getVariable(l));
            } else {
                j = j + marginalCpt.getStride(cpt.getVariable(l));
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    marginalCpt.setValues(marginalValues);


    return marginalCpt;
}
```

**Solution**

Following @the8472 suggestion of using a memory profiler I could identify the object pointed by `product` in YourKit memory snapshot. Surprisingly, after the for loop, that object disappeared! That means that possibly the debugger indeed was holding the object somehow (as suggested by other ones in this thread), stopping the GC of removing it. It was surprising for me, since I've run before a small example in a similar context and the debugger didn't hold the object in that example. I can't understand why it didn't hold that time and hold in this one, but anyway it seems to be the debugger fault.
Thanks all for your support.

Comment: What are the internals for ConditionalProbabilityTableOperation.marginalize()?

Comment: Does `ConditionalProbabilityTableOperation.marginalize` keep a reference to `product` ?

Comment: How is 'marginal ' getting constructed? Are you using any of the member references from product?

Comment: Thanks for helping. I edited the post adding the `ConditionalProbabilityTableOperation.marginalize` code. I tried to find *any* reference to `product` everywhere, but I couldn't.

Comment: How do you know that the object is not garbage collected?

Comment: @Andreas, I am using the *Variables* inspector window of the debugger inside Eclipse. With it I can check the unique assigned id given to an object pointed by `product`. Moreover, I can right-click in `product` and see *All instances...*, that is, all instances of `ConditionalProbabilityTable ` alive at that moment. In this way, I could track all `product` ids that was supposed to disappear eventually but never do.

Comment: Why are you *trying* to get rid of the object?

Comment: You can't use the debugger to check if orphaned objects are garbage collected, because the debugger may retain a weak reference to the object. Weakly referenced objects *will* be garbage collected if memory is running low, but it doesn't sound like you are running low, so you're making false conclusions.

Comment: @chrylis, my problem with that object being alive is that they are huge, so I really need that the GC eventually get rid of it for me. The code as it is right now always crash after few minutes due to lack of memory.
Thanks for discussing this point, @Andreas. I also thought about that possibility (that the debugger might be holding a reference for the objects). But I temporarily refused it after I wrote a small counter example with a similar structure. But in this smaller example the GC eventually collected the correspondent object to `product`, as expected.

Comment: The Eclipse debugger can analyze a runtime and find where references to an object are being held.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that, @chrylis. I think you're talking about the *All References* options, right? If yes, I have tried that too unsuccessfully. Just before the for loop exits, `product` has *no reference*. After the for loop, I can see the object instance alive, but I can't track references to it anymore. Or can I...? Do you know how to do this on Eclipse? Thanks.

Comment: using the debugger distorts results because it causes local variables to be held alive longer than they normally would since debugging a particular method deoptimizes that method. unless you have some indication by other means that those objects actually are leaked your initially diagnosis may have been wrong due to the debugger itself.

Comment: Thanks, @the8472. Andreas also suggested this possibility and, as I replied to him, I could simulate a similar context with a simpler example and the debugger did not interfered in those results. That is, I could see the object being deleted eventually, as expected. But, anyway, my stronger indication that those objects are leaking is the memory consumption: the code stop running after a while due to lack of memory (I'm running in a 8GB machine).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a memory profiler, create a heap dump, look for the object(s) in question, examine paths to gc roots from those objects.

The exact steps depend on the profiler/dump analyzer tool.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, @the8472. Actually, I have tried this before using YourKit (tho I used in a very simple way, I don't have a deep understanding of these techniques). The problem here is that I can't tell which object I should track down. In a dump, I would have lots of `ConditionalProbabilityTable` objects, but I couldn't find a way to detect the specific one which is related to that `product` inside the for loop. Do you have any thoughts on this?

Comment: with yourkit you can have *combined paths to GC roots* listed for that class. If there is something special about that particular loop as opposed to all the other objects then a local variable in the executing thread should show up as one of the roots.

Comment: following your suggestion I could identify the object pointed by `product` in YourKit memory snapshot. Surprisingly, after the for loop, that object disappeared! That means that possible the debugger indeed was holding the object somehow, stopping GC of removing it. It was surprising for me since I've run a small example in similar situation and the debugger didn't hold the object in that example. I can't understand why it didn't hold that time and hold in this one, but anyway it seems to be the debugger fault. I'll close this thread now. Thanks.